# How to auto-detect and export all the web links from a MS word file to a separated file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, find, hyperlink

I have a .docx file that the web links are not underlines and auto-detected as usual. Is there any way to find all the weblinks and export them to another file?

Comment: That will require a macro likely. Are the links actually links, or are they just website addresses that aren't tagged with href information? Can you do a Find and look for http/https or www strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to press Alt + F9 to show field code.

Then press Ctrl + H to open Find and Replace. Enter `"https*"`, choose Use wildcards and Main Documents.

[image]

The web links could be selected, you may copy and past them to one document. Please remember to press Alt + F9 to switch back.